# disable RHEL 8 screenlock happening within VNC session

Tags: gnome, vnc, screen-lock

In using RHEL-8.9, when I create a VNC session then connect to it for the first time I get my desktop as expected not the screenlock.  But if I disconnect my VNC session then reconnect, even if I reconnect immediately after closing it, I am presented with the basic Redhat screenlock  **within my VNC session**.  This did not happen under RHEL-7.9.

In doing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

this seems to be a per user account setting.  This stopped the screen lock from happening.  But I did this when logged in as root and it did not affect my regular user "ron" session, not until I did those two `gsettings` command under my user account.

Is there a way to make this disabling effect global?  I need all user accounts who are using VNC not to experience the screen lock within their VNC session.